# What is route test?

Tags: automated-testing, terminology

I've been asked to implement route test (integration) for a new application, but i have just a small idea of what is this, here's my thoughts about it:

*Is to test the flow of a package through his final destination. I'm aware of tracert, but i'm not sure how to automate it.*

Is there any clear explanation of what is testing routes in a integration or unit test?

Comment: Have you considered asking the person who told you to do it?

Comment: Gone on vacations :P

Comment: What is the context of the application (what does it do) and or industry (for whom)? That might help in answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most terminology this depends on the person and or the industry. Be sure to define terminology per workplace so that everyone has the same definition, in doubt always ask. :)

I have worked in market research, where route testing would mean testing all possible paths through a questionnaire. Different questions would mean skipping and or adding extra questions for this run.

In the internet industry it could indeed mean what you describe, but testing this automated would need a specific network setup where you are sure about the input and output. You could  try to simulate this with multiple VM's.

In a unittest setting it might mean testing all the branches: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184807/branch-vs-decision-coverage-question

Comment: The infrastructure team changes the rules of the firewall to maintain the security of our systems, but sometimes it blocks the communication one or more of our applications. The intention is to  prevent it to happen to (in this case) a blog.

Comment: In that case I think you want to setup network monitoring with a tool like: Nagios http://www.nagios.org/ Configure for each possible connection a check, for example is the webserver of the blog available, if you need to verify the firewall rules are still OK, it should be placed in the DMZ. This sounds more a task for the infrastructure team itself.